# Is There A Standard Location For Bash Scripts In Maven

Tags: maven

Is there a standard location for bash scripts in maven?

The [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) doesn't mention scripts at all.

Also, if I have a multi-module build, should I keep all the scripts in the dist module or in each individual module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to put them into `src/main/scripts` furthermore if you have a separate dist module which i assume should contain them put them into the dist module. I assume those scripts are part of the distribution so i would put them all into the dist module..

Comment: This sounds reasonable. Is it just an opinion though or does Maven define it somewhere? `src/main/assembly` is not for scripts then?

Comment: If you take a look at the link you have referenced which mentioned `src/assembly` and **not** `/src/main/assembly` which is intended for maven-assembly-plugin assembly descriptors...and not for scripts...

Comment: Just checking because it doesn't mention scripts at all.